# Jquery HTML(), clone

Tags: jquery, html

I have a quick question should be easy, but need to make it fast

I want to take with jquery one div and to put this div in another one, but the first one should be.

I have this HTML

```
<div class="content">Some text</div>
```

I want to put this content in another div

```
<div class="test"> content div should be here </div>
```

Jquery styff :

```
$(".content").click(function(){
                $(".test").html($(this));   
            });
```

But after that the original `<div class="content">` disappears, but I need to leave it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to clone the original div:

```
$(".content").click(function(){
    $(".test").append($(this).clone()); 
});
```