# Jquery + Clone a html code block

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is just something I looking to do - plz let me know if I'm going about it wrong.

Building a Dating Network and I need to open a chat/messenger box when required for 2 users to chat.

The chat box will basically be a DIV with required HTML/CSS/IMGs & user specific data - including jquery ui to allow movability.

Question - i'm looking for the best way to load these chat boxes.

I was planning on including the core HTML/CSS with the default page load with display:none; Then I could clone this code and create a new chat box.

Cloneing isn't something I've done before. Was interested to try it. I guess I could read and reuse the code with jquery.

Any advise with this?

thx

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156264/jquery-html-clone?rq=1 ?

Comment: Regarding your question on cloning please refer to the jQuery documentation http://api.jquery.com/clone/ , have a good read and start implementing your application. Regarding `i'm looking for the best way to load these chat boxes.`, that question is to general and not a good fit for Q&A. Start implementing something you feel is right and then come back with specific questions on specific issues you are facing during implementation.

Comment: no worries - question was premature... thankyou... :) learning...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
$(function () {
  var appendme = $("#element").html();

  $('#container').append(appendme);

});
</script>
```

or

```
$('.hello').clone().appendTo('.goodbye');
```